# as3 - Use of arrays to give letters a value of another array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

I am trying to make a chemistry calculator where I can put in the elements letters, like "H", "He", "O", etc, so I have made an array called elements. Then I have made an array with the values. I want for the letters.

Is there any way to make it that if I write `element[x]` it would use the `value[x]`?

```
var element:Array = new Array("H", "O")
var mass:Array = new Array(1.01, 16.01);

function elements() {
if (input_Mm.text == element[0]) {
    Mm = mass[0];
}
if (input_Mm.text == element[1]) {
    Mm = mass[1];
}
}
```

So, I don't have to write one if statement for each and every possible element.

Comment: what? did you mean an auto complete ?

Comment: i mean i need some way to not have to use hundreds of if commands, i'll edit the code in the question so you can see how it is now

Answer (score 2):

You could use a loop to loop through your element array, then take the index found to look up the mass array.

A better option may be to use a dictionary object to do a direct lookup, which might be better in this case. You can think of dictionaries as  being similar to arrays, but with strings as the key instead of an index number.

In both cases, you may also want to filter bad input if "input_Mm" is a user editable field.

Comment: Thank you soo much

Answer (score 2):

use object

```
var element_mass:Object = {
    H: 1.01,
    O: 16.01
}

function elements() {
  if(element_mass.hasOwnProperty(input_Mm.text))
      Mm = element_mass[input_Mm.text];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The Mendeleiev table contains 103 elements, so You may use a fixed Vector to store de datas...

Just to make it simple...

```
var mendeleievElmnt:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>(103,true);
var mendeleievMass:Vector.<Number> = new Vector.<Number>(103,true);
// 103 elements... So a fixed Vector. :)
function populateMeElmnts():void{
    mendeleievElmnt[0] = "H";
    mendeleievElmnt[1] = "He";
    mendeleievElmnt[2] = "Li";
    mendeleievElmnt[3] = "Be";
    //...
}
function populateMeMass():void{
    mendeleievMass[0] = 1;
    mendeleievMass[1] = 4;
    mendeleievMass[2] = 6.9;
    mendeleievMass[3] = 9;
    //...
    // O is 16 and not 16.1 but I'm old school ;)
}
populateMeElmnts()
populateMeMass()
function getElement(el:uint):String{
    return ("element[" + (el+1) + "] = " + mendeleievElmnt[el] + ", mass = " + mendeleievMass[el]);
}
trace(getElement(2));
//OR
function returnElement(el:uint):Object{
    var o:Object = new Object()

    o["elm"]= mendeleievElmnt[el];
    o["elMass"]= mendeleievMass[el];
    o["elIndex"]= el+1;
    return o;
}
var elmt:Object = returnElement(2);
trace("index = " + elmt["elIndex"] + ", elm= " + elmt["elm"] + ", elmtMass = " + elmt["elMass"]);
```

Output:

```
// element[3] = Li, mass = 6.9
// index = 3, elm= Li, elmtMass = 6.9
```

The Vector Class is really more efficient but I don't know if You expect to fill all those data dynamically...
In this example, You have to populate the 103 Elements and their Mm in the two functions.

Do You want to fill those data via a database dynamically???

Anyway I strongly suggest You to avoid Objects or Arrays...

There's a lot of possibilities, so this is unclear to me...
Sorry if the answer is not accurate so.

1° : Why do you want to get an object in place of get an index of a Vector?
2° : What's the project must look like?

The answer of @GeorgeProfenza looks perfect in your case and gives You the opportunity to work in different directions.

Best regards.
Nicolas

Answer (score 1):

There multiple ways to do this.
The `Object` approach payam sbr suggest is pretty straight forward.

To add to the existing answers: you could write a class to represent a chemical object value object(VO) (e.g. store it's name, notation, mass, etc.):

```
package  {

    public class Element {

        private var _name:String;
        private var _notation:String;
        private var _mass:Number;

        public function Element(name:String,notation:String,mass:Number) {
            _name = name;
            _notation = notation;
            _mass = mass;
        }

        public function getName():String{
            return _name;
        }
        public function setName(newName:String):void{
            _name = newName;
        }

        public function getNotation():String{
            return _notation;
        }
        public function setNotation(newNotation:String):void{
            _notation = newNotation;
        }

        public function getMass():Number{
            return _mass;
        }
        public function setMass(newMass:Number):void{
            _mass = newMass;
        }

        public function toString():String{
                return "[Element name="+_name+" notation="+_notation+" mass="+_mass+"]";
        }
    }

}
```

You could then create a one dimensional array of Elements and access the data each Element stores:

```
var elements:Vector.<Element> = new Vector.<Element>();

elements.push(new Element("Hydrogen","H",1.01));
elements.push(new Element("Oxygen","O",16.01));

var totalMass:Number = 0;

for(var i:int = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    trace("elements[",i,"]",elements[i]);
    totalMass += elements[i].getMass();
}

trace("total mass",totalMass);
```

Outputs:

```
elements[ 0 ] [Element name=Hydrogen notation=H mass=1.01]
elements[ 1 ] [Element name=Oxygen notation=O mass=16.01]
total mass 17.020000000000003
```

Note that a typed Vector will be faster than an untyped `Array` of `Object` instances. Additionally as3.0 getters/setters can be a bit slow to, hence the code java style get / set methods.

If you don't plan to go though a HUGE amount of elements and performance doesn't have to be as tight as possible you can use the typical as3 getter/setters that behave like properties (if this is more readable/easier to understand):

```
package  {

    public class Element {

        private var _name:String;
        private var _notation:String;
        private var _mass:Number;

        public function Element(name:String,notation:String,mass:Number) {
            _name = name;
            _notation = notation;
            _mass = mass;
        }

        public function get name():String{
            return _name;
        }
        public function set name(newName:String):void{
            _name = newName;
        }

        public function get notation():String{
            return _notation;
        }
        public function set notation(newNotation:String):void{
            _notation = newNotation;
        }

        public function get mass():Number{
            return _mass;
        }
        public function set mass(newMass:Number):void{
            _mass = newMass;
        }

        public function toString():String{
                return "[Element name="+_name+" notation="+_notation+" mass="+_mass+"]";
        }
    }

}
```

test code:

```
var elements:Vector.<Element> = new Vector.<Element>();

elements.push(new Element("Hydrogen","H",1.01));
elements.push(new Element("Oxygen","O",16.01));

var totalMass:Number = 0;

for(var i:int = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
    trace("elements[",i,"]",elements[i]);
    totalMass += elements[i].mass;
}

trace("total mass",totalMass);
```

If you use a class versus `Object` you'll also get auto-complete.

If you want an option closer to the `Object` approach with less code for a quick prototype, you can probably get away with public properties:

```
package  {

    public class Element {

        public var name:String;
        public var notation:String;
        public var mass:Number;

        public function Element(name:String,notation:String,mass:Number) {
            this.name = name;
            this.notation = notation;
            this.mass = mass;
        }

        public function toString():String{
                return "[Element name="+name+" notation="+notation+" mass="+mass+"]";
        }
    }

}
```